# Date from the form is on the right format but dont pass the validation on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create my first update of my CRUD but im getting an weird validation error. On my view, there's a field to input a date. It comes to my controller on the format: **dd/mm/yyyy**

So on my **Events** controller, the update and the require_params looks like this:

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    puts '----params date----' 
    puts event_params[:date]
    puts '----params date----' 
    if @event.update_attributes(event_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Evento atualizado com sucesso."
      redirect_to @event
    else
      @event_count = Event.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:event, :place, :link, :participants, :date)
    end
```

And my **event** model:

```
# include ER
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    scope    :datedesc, lambda {order("date desc")}

    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
        :date => "Data"
    }

    def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
      HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
    end

    validates :event, :place, :link, :participants, :date, presence: true
    validates :event, :place, :link, :participants, length: { maximum: 255 }
    # validates :date, format: {with: ER::DATE, message: "Data fora do padrão", :multiline => true}
    validates :date, format: {:with => /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/, :message => "Data precisa estar no padrão dd/mm/yyyy"}
end
```

So, when I press submit on the view, I keep getting the message of my date validation. But the date is coming on the right format. Im seeing it on the console using the put command.

Im finding very hard to debug on rails, so, sometimes the console doesnt show all the information that I wanted and I keep getting stucked. Why the update is not working, and, is there something that I can do to improve the debug of my apps? Like, on php, i could do var_dump and die wherever I wanted, using rails, I dont know if I can do something like that. Can I?

This is the output on my console:

```
Started PATCH "/admin/events/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-23 13:34:13 -0300
Processing by Admin::EventsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZVX7nRd67A0RDlYwcgKRyLLsh4GicmicF7AWB6LWGtnzT4T79GkHk8DJyZLQm2lc4gos1idZ5LYGz37Nv97Wrg==", "event"=>{"event"=>"Evento 1", "place"=>"Rua Teste 123", "link"=>"www.google.com", "participants"=>"Felipe, Fernando, Rodrigo", "date"=>"25/02/2017"}, "commit"=>"Atualizar Evento", "id"=>"1"}
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
----params date----
25/02/2017
----params date----
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `events`
  Rendering admin/events/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin
  Rendered admin/events/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered admin/events/edit.html.erb within layouts/admin (39.0ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered admin/_rodape.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 257ms (Views: 200.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Rails.logger might be useful for such kind of debugging, also, there is a nice gem called byebug. If you want something similar to var_dump, you might want to try calling an inspect method on the objects you are trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about debugging @zilvinas. Do you know what could be happening with my validation process?

Comment: I am not sure, I would suggest doing some of my suggested begugging. Maybe something goes wrong in the event_params method. And a small tip: the way you are validating the date is not the best practice since this regex rule still allows a range of invalid dates. Instead, in addition to format validation I would recommend adding a custom validation block where you could try to parse a given date and return false if parsing fails.

Comment: Also, it is possible that the date attribute in your model is not a string but a datetime object. In such case format does not matter. You only need to check if the date can be parsed (is valid).

Comment: You have a bunch of puts statements... but haven't shown us the output from those... can you edit your question and add that there? Consider also: "42/42/9999" would pass your validation-format, but still not be a valid date. But I agree... your date can come through as an already-parsed ruby `Date`... which would fail the format-validation, but still be legal. So I suggest only validating the format if the `date` field is a string ?

Comment: @TarynEast I edit my post and paste my console information. I didnt understand what you said. I should validate the format if the date field is a string? But, every params attributes dont always come to the controller as a string? I should see if it is empty or not? Someyhing like that?

Comment: @zilvinas where do I check that? On the controller? Or is there a validate method to put on the model for that?

Comment: I assume that the type of your model's date attribute is datetime (you can check it in the database ("DESC events;" for MySQL) or in your migrations). However, you are trying to validate it as a string which will never succeed. Instead, your should just make sure that the date is valid. This can be done in the model. If I am right, by trying to save some date like "13/13/2017" will result in ArgumentError: argument out of range exception. This indicates that the date is invalid.

Comment: @zilvinas so, I dont need any validation on the model for the date input? Just have to save the params and handle the exception? How to handle this ArgumentError, it will show an error on the front-end, right? How do I handle it?

Comment: 1) Yes, you should still validate the date. If you don't validate, you won't get nice error messages, but a big explosion instead. 2) Rails knows that your date column is a date. Rails converts the date-string into a date as it comes in via input. Therefore, by the time that you are validating the date... it's not a string, but a ruby `DateTime`  object. 3) `validates_format_of` works only on strings. It validates that the format of the string the user typed matches the `Regex` you gave. But as I just said... you don't have a string anymore - you have a `DateTime`

Comment: For me, thats a bit confusing @TarynEast. So, on the model I just need to check if the attribute is empty? Cause, if its already coming as a date object, the only thing I can check is if its not empty, right?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide an answer to your comment here. There's usually no best way of doing something, my suggested way is how I might deal with this kind of situation.
About the exception handing in ruby you can learn here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Exception.html.
For custom validation please read: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate.
You can the combine custom validation and exception handling to solve your problem. Also, it is possible to do it in your controller by wrapping the updating of an object in a begin/rescue clause.